# how could i open popup window based on two select option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to design the following scenario using `html`, `css` and `javascript`: I have created one dropdown menu where you should select a city [ex. Chandigarh]. When you've selected a city, the corresponding algorithms will come with a drop down menu [ex. PSO,GA,BBO]. If I select PSO then another popup window will open and there will be another dropdown menu with list of years [ex. 2030, 2035, 2040]. 
How could I design the following scenario?

I am able to do to open popup window using one select option. I have added the code with a dummy url. But for multiple select option I need help.

```js
function openPop() {
  var Sel_Ind = document.getElementById('myURLs').selectedIndex;
  var popUrl = document.getElementById('myURLs').options[Sel_Ind].value;
  winpops = window.open(popUrl, "", "width=600,height=600,resizable,")
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pop URL on Select</title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="myURLs" onChange="javascript:openPop();">
    <option value="">Select a page...</option>
    <option value="http://news.bbc.co.uk">PSO</option>
    <option value="http://www.the-company.com">GA</option>
    <option value="http://www.b3ta.com">BBO</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">DE</option>
    <option value="http://www.sitepoint.com/forums">Help</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```